# Цикл while  «Сумма последовательности чисел»

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте.

Начал изучать питон, иногда нападают жуткие тупняки. Ряд задач с этим циклом, вроде, решен и понятен, тут не могу никак понять, как формулировать решение.

Определите сумму всех элементов последовательности, завершающейся числом 0. В этой и во всех следующих задачах числа, следующие за первым нулем, учитывать не нужно.
def по этому курсу еще не было, не знаю, что это. Т.е. задачу нужно решить, исходя из того, что материал был по

Занятие 1. Ввод-вывод, арифметические операции

Занятие 2. Условная инструкция

Занятие 3. Операции с целыми и вещественными числами

Занятие 4. Цикл for

Занятие 5. Строки

Занятие 6. Цикл while

Вот просто чего не понял.

```
i = 0
while int(input()) > 0:
    i += int(input())
print(i)
```

Но в этом случае суммируются элементы без первого, т.е. в том порядке, как входят, если делаю

```
i = 0
a = 0
while int(input()) >0:
    i += 1 
for j in range(0:a):
    a += int(input())
print(a)
```

то говорит, что закончились числа для ввода. Т.е. в целом я понимаю, что вообще что-то не то делаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что функция `input()` вызывается в двух местах, нужно вызывать её только в одном месте и использовать одно и то же возвращаемое значение как для проверки на ноль, так и для суммирования:

```
total = 0 # общая сумма
while True: # бесконечный цикл
    n = int(input()) # каждая строка содержит целое число
    if n == 0: # нашли нуль
        break  # выходим из цикла
    total += n # суммируем
print(total) # печатаем результат
```

Код предполагает, что каждая последовательность завершается нулём. В противном случае нужно ловить `EOFError` исключение и обрабатывать возвращаемую пустую строку.

Чтобы самостоятельно найти ошибку в своём коде, в таких простых случаях, полезно выписать словами, что код делает строчка за строчкой (отладка [методом утёнка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%83%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

---

Другие способы выразить то же самое для тестов (и для улучшения понимания задачи людьми, которые уже знают Питон, не для прямого использования):

```
import sys
from itertools import takewhile

print(sum(takewhile(lambda n: n != 0, map(int, sys.stdin))))
```

Не нулевые целые числа являются истиной в булевом контексте в Питоне, поэтому вместо 
`lambda n: n != 0` можно использовать просто `bool` (менее читаемый (явный) вариант).

Или даже (если каждая строчка содержит только числа, без пробелов):

```
print(sum(map(int, iter(input, '0'))))
```

Comment: В общем, все дело в break, я просто не понимал, как работает это прерывание, большое спасибо за настолько развернутый ответ.

Comment: В общем, после решения ответа в курсе показывает эталонный ответ.
В нем решение даже без прерывания только с использованием цикла "While". Проблема с функцией input() решается присваиванием ей вначале переменной, которая потом и суммируется. Но это просто еще раз показывает, что решать задачи можно разными способами.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, насколько я понимаю, проходить в цикле элементы, суммируя их, пока значение элемента не будет 0. Если 0 - покидаем цикл.

Comment: @Tetracon, погугли «python условный оператор» (aka «оператор ветвления», «if») и «python прерывание цикла». Про while, for и арифметику уже знаешь, этого достаточно для выполнения задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так (проверял только глазами, вроде все правильно, в любом случае главное - принцип):

```
def sum0(lst):
    if 0 in lst:
        return sum(lst[:lst.index(0)])
    else:
        return sum(lst)
```

Comment: @Tetracon, def это определение функции. Можно убрать def и самому положить в переменную lst нужный список.
А вообще нет ничего крамольного в том, чтобы забегать вперёд и самостоятельно находить знания недостающие для решения проблемы. Если кто-то (препод или кто там) считает иначе и уверен, что нельзя использовать функции, пока он о них не расскажет — шлите его куда подальше (можно громко и матом), он вредитель.

Comment: Можно и без def:

    print(sum(lst[:lst.index(0)]) if 0 in lst else sum(lst))

Comment: Данный ответ предполагает, что ввод сохранен в списке, что совсем необязательно -- достаточно только два числа хранить: текущее и общую сумму.  
Можно обойтись без просмотра списка три раза (0 in lst, lst.index(0), sum(lst)):

   def stop():
       raise StopIteration
   print(sum(n for n in lst if n or stop()))

(в обычном коде вместо `stop()` хака, можно использовать явный цикл  `break`).