# Сумма чисел из стандартного ввода

Tags: python, input

Необходимо написать программу, которая считывает со стандартного ввода целые числа по одному числу и после первого введённого нуля - выводит сумму полученных на вход чисел.

Не понимаю - где ошибка?

```
text = int(input("Вводите значение: "))  # вводим элементы массива

while text != (int(0)):  # цикл - до тех пор, пока -text != 0, добавляет значения в массив -a
    a.append(text)  # добавляем значение в массив

    if text == (int(0)):  # если -text == 0, выводим сумму всех элементов массива
        print(sum(a))  # суммируем между собой все элементы массива
```

Comment: прикрепите в вопрос текст ошибки

Comment: @alex9127... Когда в консоли ввожу: 1, 2, 3... - процесс НЕ завещается.

А если ввожу: 0 - процесс завершается.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Цикл while  «Сумма последовательности чисел»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/384437/%d0%a6%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-while-%d0%a1%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас не объявлен список `a`.
Бесконечный цикл работает не так, как нужно. На каждой итерации цикла после добавления нужно запрашивать новое значение.

```
text = int(input("Вводите значение: "))  # вводим элементы массива
a = []

while text != 0:  # цикл - до тех пор, пока -text != 0, добавляет значения в массив -a
    a.append(text)  # добавляем значение в массив
    text = int(input("Вводите значение: "))

print(sum(a))  # суммируем между собой все элементы массива
```

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО, всё работает!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Вы вводите число одни раз в самом начале.

Допустим, вы ввели 9. Далее цикл выполняется, пока `9 != 0`, то есть бесконечно, так как новые числа не вводятся. Нужно просто добавить ввод данных в цикл.

---

Также можно перенести вывод суммы из цикла, чтобы не проверять условие каждый раз.
И ещё, нет никакого смысла в записи `int(0)`

Например, можно сделать так:

```
arr = []
num = int(input("Вводите значение: "))
while num != 0:
    num = int(input("Вводите значение: "))
    arr.append(num)

print(sum(arr))
```

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО, всё работает!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Лучше в данном случае использовать "бесконечный цикл", чтобы ввод значения не делать два раза в разных местах:

```
a = []
while True:
    num = int(input("Вводите значение: ")) 
    if num == 0:
        print(sum(a))
        break
    a.append(num)
```

Ну а ошибки и недочёты вам уже все написали в других ответах.

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО, всё работает!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с [python-3.8](/questions/tagged/python-3.8) в язык добавлен [walrus operator `:=`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), использование которого может немного сократить объем кода в таких задачах, как в вопросе.

Также можно избежать явного сравнения с `0`, полагаясь на неявное приведение к `bool`.

```
s = 0
while number := int(input("input: ")):
    s += number
print(s)
```